# Best practice for formatting scraped HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yql

I have inherited some code which uses a YQL query to grab all the HTML from an external site. The data is then filtered and then outputted to a container. The YQL query is not returning XML but rather HTML, I've tried changing the format to JSON without luck. Maybe I'm messing up the syntax.

Here is the YQL query:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" +
                "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" +
                encodeURIComponent(url) +
                "%22&format=JSON&callback=?",
```

this data is then passed to this filter function (this is not the entire piece of code)

```
function filterData(data) {

        data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<p>5\) \{ return; }.* \} \}; <\/p>/, '');
        data = data.replace(/<body[^>]*>/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<hr[^>]*>/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<table[^>]*>/g, '<table>');

        return data;
}
```

I feel like there must be a better way to either put this returned HTML data into some sort of template or something, I'm pretty unfamiliar with jQuery, any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's odd... I've always received JSON from that service, but I haven't used it in years.

Comment: I'd just drop the HTML into a invisible DOV (`$("#invisible").html(data)`) and then just use normal jQuery selectors so search and remove/clean up anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to grab them as JSON for easier processing in jQuery. You just need to make sure uppercase `JSON` is changed to lowercase `json` to get JSON output from the API.

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" +
                "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" +
                encodeURIComponent(url) +
                "%22&format=json&callback=?",
```

Comment: I think in the long run that's the best solution, the data will be easier to work with. Thank you!